"Could not find server in sys.servers", not sure why I am getting this error?
Here is my code. I am trying to run my stored procedure that updates my tables:
import pyodbc
import logging
import json
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import warnings
import time


def to_varbinary(val):     
    return bytes(val, 'utf-8')


def pop_abc_insert():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    start_time = time.time()

    with open(r'upsert_config.json','r') as ts:
        config = json.load(ts)

    ABC_driver = config['ABC_layer']['ABC_driver']
    ABC_server = config['ABC_layer']['ABC_server']
    ABC_database = config['ABC_layer']['ABC_database']
    POP_driver = config['POP_layer']['POP_driver']
    POP_server = config ['POP_layer']['POP_server']
    POP_database = config['POP_layer']['POP_database']


    conn = pyodbc.connect(
    f'Driver={ABC_driver};'
    f'Server={ABC_server};'
    f'Database={ABC_database};'
    f'Driver={POP_driver};'
    f'Server={POP_server};'
    f'Database={POP_database};'
    f'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    f'MARS_Connection=Yes'
    )

    try:
        ABC_database=f'{ABC_database}.dbo'
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        read_table_query="""        
        SELECT table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME_HERE'
        ORDER BY table_name asc
            """
        cursor.execute(read_table_query)  
        print(read_table_query)

        logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))    

    for tables in cursor.fetchall():
        tab = tables[0]
        ABC_POP_query = f"""
                            update {POP_database}.dbo.{tab} SET
                            Active_ind = 0,
                            expiry_date = GETDATE(), 
                            updated_date = GETDATE()
                            WHERE convert(    varbinary,hash_key )IN (
                            SELECT convert(    varbinary,T1.hash_key)
                            FROM {ABC_database}.dbo.{tab} T1 LEFT JOIN
                                {POP_database}.dbo.{tab} T2 ON convert(    varbinary,T1.hash_key) = convert(    varbinary,T2.hash_key)
                            WHERE convert(    varbinary,T1.hash_dif) <> convert(    varbinary,T2.hash_dif)
                            AND T1.Active_ind = 1
                            ) AND Active_ind = 1
                            
                            insert into {POP_database}.dbo.{tab} 
                            select * from {ABC_database}.dbo.{tab}
                            WHERE convert(varbinary,hash_key) IN (
                            SELECT convert(varbinary,T1.hash_key)
                            FROM {ABC_database}.dbo.{tab} T1 LEFT JOIN
                                {POP_database}.dbo.{tab} T2 ON convert(    varbinary,T1.hash_key) = convert(    varbinary,T2.hash_key)
                            WHERE convert(    varbinary,T1.hash_dif) <> convert(    varbinary,T2.hash_dif)
                            AND T1.Active_ind = 1)
                                                    
                            insert into {POP_database}.dbo.{tab}
                            select * from {ABC_database}.dbo.{tab} 
                            WHERE convert(varbinary, hash_key) NOT IN (
                            SELECT convert(varbinary,T2.hash_key)
                            FROM {POP_database}.dbo.{tab} T2
                            WHERE T2.Active_ind = 1)

                            """
        cursor.execute(ABC_POP_query)
         

pop_abc_insert()

Here is my config in JSON format:
{
    "ABC_layer":
    {
        "ABC_driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "ABC_server": "SERVER1",
        "ABC_database": "ABC"    
    },

    "POP_layer":
    {
        "POP_driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "POP_server": "SERVER1",
        "POP_database": "POP"    
    }    
}

I am getting this error:

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find server 'ABC' in sys.servers.
Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers. (7202) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I am trying to update the tables on the same server so I don't need to link the servers or anything right? The tables are in different databases but both are SQL Server. Is there an error in my code?

That code looks dangerously open to injection. Why are you blindly injecting object names in your query? That is why you have the error; you are blindly injecting {ABC_database}.dbo as your database name. Databases can be easily parametrised in the connection string. The need for performing the same UPDATE against every table in the database suggests an XY Problem to me.

As far as I know you can execute queries that refer to tables in different databases - but I don't think you can assume that every user has access to any two particular databases so that might not work for whatever privileges this connection has.

there's so much wrong here apart from the bad injection issue: use of hashes as pretend-version-control instead of just comparing the columns that need comparing. Use of varbinary without a length. INSERT without specifying the columns. Why do you need to convert those columns in the first place, why aren't they in the right data type?  Unnecessary self-join against the table you are modifying anyway. Use of LEFT JOIN which is implicitly an inner join due to the WHERE. Use of INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of sys.tables.

"Perhaps one of the values substituted for {tab} contains a period (.)" No, @testing-ma-lady , as mentioned in my comment, they set the variable ABC_database to be f'{ABC_database}.dbo', and then inject that in a statement like FROM {ABC_database}.dbo.{tab}. Assuming ABC_database initially have the value MyDatabase that would resolve to  MyDatabase.dbo.dbo.<Table Name>; so they are after data from the table <Table Name> on the schema dbo, in the database dbo on the  server MyDatabase. It's a typographical error at best, but really a ticking timebomb.

yes @thom A that was the issue, i had '.dbo.dbo.' twice for the ABC database in my query. easy fix! but when i run my script, although there is no error, it doesn't actually execute the SQL i have written even though it says it ran

actually nevermind i figured it out, i needed to add cursor.commit() now it works. thanks all!

The script is still severly broken with all that injection, @Forgottenluv ...
